# Javascript Algorithm Maximum subarray

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, kadanes-algorithm

I get that question from leet code and I got this answer from YouTube tutorial, but I don't understand the part of max. Because max is `arr[0]` and the value is `-2`, and even it goes inside of the loop, it is just `-2` but max returns value `6`.

How it possible?

```js
const givenArray = [-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4];
const getMax = arr => {
  let sum = arr[0]; //-2
  let max = arr[0]; //-2
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum = Math.max(sum + arr[i], arr[i]);
    max = Math.max(max, sum);

  }

  console.log(sum);
  console.log(max);
};

getMax(givenArray);
```

Comment: "*and even it goes inside of the loop, it is just -2*" but it's overwritten within the loop, it doesn't stay `-2` forever?

Comment: @VLAZ if I console.log(max) inside of for loop it only shows -2, for 9times

Comment: [No, it doesn't](https://jsbin.com/vusevapeho/edit?js,console)

Comment: @VLAZ but the How the max number comes from?

Comment: @VLAZ okay so Index change after Math.max function? arr[0] is not -2 anymore?

Comment: `max = Math.max(max, sum)` assigns a new value on each iteration. It will only keep the same value if *max* is always equal to or larger than *sum* from the beginning.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/goquyixagi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: ahhhh thanks a lot both of you guys. now I got it!!

Comment: As a tangential side note, this is an exceptional level of patience for a Javascript question on Stack Overflow, props to both of you VLAZ and RobG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max=-2 sum=-2

loop arr[1]=1: sum = max( -2 + 1, 1) = 1, max = max( sum=1 , max=-2 ) = 1

max=1 sum=1

loop arr[2]=-3: sum = max( 1 + -3, -3) = -2, max = max( sum=-2, max=1 ) = 1

max=1 sum=-2

loop arr[3]=4: sum = max( -3 + 4, 4) = 4, max = max( sum=4, max=1 ) = 4

max=4 sum=4

loop arr[4]=-1: sum = max( 4 + -1, -1) = 3, max = (3,4) = 4

max=4 sum=3

loop arr[5]=2: sum = max( 3 + 2, 2) = 5, max = max(5,4) = 5

So the iteration looks like this:

```
arr [-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]  
sum   x, 1,  x, 4,  3, 5, 6,  1, 5  

max  -2, 1,  1, 4,  4, 5, 6,  6, 6
```

It's like finding progressive sums, discarding negative sequences or starting off a new sequence when sum is negative, because any negative sequence would contribute negatively to the total sum of a sequence.

And, you use max = Math.max(max, sum), (set max to what's bigger, current max value or current sum) to find the largest value reached in the progressive sums (which is 6).
This also accounts for edge case of all negatives, where the maximal sum will be the largest negative number.

```js
const givenArray = [-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4];
const getMax = arr => {
  let sum = arr[0]; //-2
  let max = arr[0]; //-2
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum = Math.max(sum + arr[i], arr[i]);
    max = Math.max(max, sum);
    console.log(`max=${max}`, `sum=${sum}`);
  }

};

getMax(givenArray);
```